# Composer issues when trying to upgrade

Tags: composer, 10

I'm trying to upgrade from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10, and I'm running into errors from composer. Here's the command I'm using:

```
composer require drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.5 drupal/core-recommended:10.1.5 -W
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.5].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.5 requires drupal/core 10.1.5 -> found drupal/core[10.1.5] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
enter code here
```

And here's what `composer why-not drupal/core 10.1.5` says after I upgraded as many modules as I could:

```
drupal/core-recommended        9.5.11 requires         drupal/core (9.5.11)                                    
drupal/csv_serialization       2.1.0  requires         drupal/core (^8 || ^9)                                  
drupal/hook_event_dispatcher   3.3.4  requires         drupal/core (^9.3)                                      
drupal/remove_http_headers     1.0.0  requires         drupal/core (^8.6||^9.0)
```

For those three modules, I've updated them in composer.json to look like this:

```
"drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.0 || ^3.0",
"drupal/hook_event_dispatcher": "^3.3 || ^4.0",
"drupal/remove_http_headers": "^1.0 || ^2.0",
```

Which in theory should allow those upgrades (which can't happen in D9) come along for the ride.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Before upgrade to D10 run https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status module and see report about site modules and compatibility with D10

Comment: You could perhaps add the composer.json file in its original state to the Question for an objective answer.

Comment: The original state didn't have the added || conditions on those three modules and had some patches that were no longer required. I can add the entire composer.json here if needed but that seems excessive.

Comment: upgrade_status told me what I already knew, those three modules have upgrades available but they can't be upgraded until core is upgraded

Comment: Assuming you are using version control, delete `composer.lock` and `vendor` and then try running the install.  For major upgrades, this will regenerate `composer.lock` and can be faster than figuring out what the exact snag is.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this helped locate a module that needed updating that previous methods hadn't identified.

Comment: I would remove those modules, upgrade core, then re-add those modules. Easier than trying to do it in one shot.

Comment: AFAIK you can just require all the desired versions in one composer statement, e.g `composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.5 drupal/csv_serialization:^3.0 drupal/hook_event_dispatcher:^4.0 drupal/remove_http_headers:^2.0 -W --dry-run `

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade Drupal 9 to Drupal 10 be sure to follow the [official guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10/overview) and the [Upgrading a Composer-based site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site) procedure.

To avoid a chicken-and-egg problem with mutual dependencies use this command :

```
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update
```

> Note that the `--no-update` option that is important here.

And then do the upgrade :

```
composer update
```

In case of rare ultimate bad luck where this is not working :

- Uninstall the modules that are causing problems
- Do the upgrade with composer
- Reinstall the modules in the Drupal 10 version compatible

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have "drupal/core" in direct/indirect dependencies, 'drupal/core-recommended' is now default package for projects created from sometime, you need to remove "drupal/core", I also run into similar issue, manually deleting "drupal/core" from composer.json file and then running

```
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update
```

solved the problem for me.
You can check more details here
[drupal/core vs. drupal/core-recommended](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295618/drupal-core-vs-drupal-core-recommended)